# ack regex: Matching two words in order in the same line

Tags: regex, ack

I would like to find lines in files that include two words, `word_1` and `word_2` in order, such as in `Line A` below, but not as in `Line B` or `Line C`:

```
Line A: ... word_1 .... word_2 .... 
Line B: ... word_1 ....
Line C: ... word_2 ....
```

I have tried

```
$ack '*word_1*word_2'
$ack '(word_1)+*(word_2)+'
```

and the same commands with `^` appended at the beginning of the regex (in an attempt to follow the Perl regex syntax).

None of these commands return the files or the lines I am interested in.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You want to find `word_1`, followed by anything, any number of times, followed by `word_2`.  That should be

```
word_1.*word_2
```

You seem to be using `*` as it is often used in command line searches, but in regexes is it a quantifier for the preceding character, meaning match it at least 0 times.  For example, the regex `a*` would match 0 or more `a`s, whereas the regex `a+` would match at least one `a`.

The regex metacharacter meaning "match anything" is `.`, so `.*` means "match anything, any number of times.  See [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Matching-repetitions) for a brief introduction on the topic.

Comment: Thanks @dsolimano! Would there be any difference between what you wrote and: `.*word_1.*word_2`. If not, why?

Comment: Sort of, but not for what you're looking at.  That would additionally match everything before `word_1` on the line.  If you were looking at what matched, as opposed to if it matched or not, you would see more stuff in the match.  If you have some cash and time, I would recommend reading "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Friedl, it's excellent.