# MongoDB: search by match of the input string or single words from the input string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have field `message` in a collection `messages`, for example:

```
[
  {
   _id: "chrYMAqT8meXpqdrC",
   message: "Hello world. This is mongo"
  },
  {
   _id: "rKu5gf5zL6NaSvZ5Q",
   message: "Hello. This is mongo world"
  },
  {
   _id: "rKu5gf5zL6NaSvZ5Q",
   message: "world. This is mongo Hello"
  }
]
```

I want to search for messages where the `message` field contains `/Hello world/ig` or where the `message` field contains the words `Hello` and `word`. And most importantly - the words must be found in the order of the input string, so the last element in the collection must not be found, but the first two must. I know how to find by matching with regex, but in the second case i don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `$regex` with the regex [`Hello.*world`](https://regex101.com/r/8SbwHE/1). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607981)

```
db.collection.find({
  message: {
    $regex: "Hello.*world",
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BLwyvVgJ2IW)

or you could use [`$regexMatch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/#-regexmatch--aggregation-)

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $regexMatch: {
      input: "$message",
      regex: "Hello.*world",
      options: "i"
    }
  }
})
])
```

`options: "i"` means case-insensitive. remove that if you don't want it

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HiiB8uw92zr)

Comment: I won't always have Hello world in the input string, there may be different words and different amounts

Comment: @Marty what do u mean can give an example

Comment: Imagine input in html and script that listen input change and sends entered string to a server. On a server I receive string and I don't know what in that string. What can I do with unknown string to use regex `word1.*word2...wordN`, there can be N words in the input string?

Comment: You can build the regex dynamically in your code before you call the query

Comment: @Marty  are you referring to something like this `"word1 word2 word3".replace(/ /g,".*")` or  `"word1 word2 word3".split(" ").join(".*")`. not sure what the string you get looks like

Comment: yep. early morning affects the absence of the brain :-D I can split the string. Thanks :)